# Custom list environment across multiple tabular columns

Tags: macros, vertical-alignment, lists, environments

I'm trying to define a custom `usecase` environment with the ability to typeset paths in the form of lists within a `tabular`environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs,multicol,enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,nosep}

\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{\sffamily#1}}

\newcounter{usecase}
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{usecase}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lp{0.8\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    \tabhead{case~\theusecase} & \tabhead{#1}\\
    \midrule
    }
    {\bottomrule\end{tabular}\end{center}}


\newcommand{\actor}[1]{actor & #1\\}

% This doesn't work.
\newenvironment{brokenmainpath}{
    main path & \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{enumerate}}
    {\end{enumerate}\end{minipage}\\}

% This does.
\newenvironment{mainpath}{
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{enumerate}}
    {\end{enumerate}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

% This works.
\begin{usecase}{important use case}
    \actor{actor 1}
    main path & \begin{mainpath}
        \item step 1
        \item step 2
    \end{mainpath}\\
\end{usecase}

% This is what I would like to type to get output in the above image.
%\begin{usecase}{important use case}
%    \actor{actor 1}
%    \begin{mainpath}
%        \item step 1
%        \item step 2
%    \end{mainpath}
%\end{usecase}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, when I include the `main path &` into the environment definition (as in `brokenmainpath`) that should always come in the left column of any use case followed by the steps of the path as an enumerated list in the right column, I get a whole bunch of errors (18 to be precise). They are all of the sort

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.  \unskip \hfil }
>                             \hskip \tabcolsep \endtemplate  l.36         \begin{brokenmainpath}

Also, the top alignment of "main path" doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Skillmon Ah I see. You're right. I'll remove the update then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use the answer from the link Salim Bou posted, or you don't use an environment but a command for `mainpath` (but this way `\verb` doesn't work):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs,multicol,enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,nosep}

\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{\sffamily#1}}

\newcounter{usecase}
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{usecase}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lp{0.8\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    \tabhead{case~\theusecase} & \tabhead{#1}\\
    \midrule
    }
    {\\\bottomrule\end{tabular}\end{center}}


\newcommand{\actor}[1]{actor & #1\\}

\newcommand\mainpath[1]{%
    main path &\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{enumerate}%
        #1%
    \end{enumerate}\end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{usecase}{important use case}
    \actor{actor 1}
    \mainpath{%
        \item step 1
        \item step 2
    }
\end{usecase}

\end{document}
```

Please note that I changed your `usecase` environment to include the `\\` before `\bottomrule`.

EDIT: For top alignment use `\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}`. Below an example using `environ` and therefore an environment for your problem and with top-alignment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs,enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,nosep}

\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{\sffamily#1}}

\newcounter{usecase}
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{usecase}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lp{0.8\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    \tabhead{case~\theusecase} & \tabhead{#1}\\
    \midrule
    }
    {\\\bottomrule\end{tabular}\end{center}}


\newcommand{\actor}[1]{actor & #1\\}

%\newenvironment{mainpath}{\mainpth}{}
\NewEnviron{mainpath}{%
    \xdef\EnvironmentContents{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
    \gdef\TableRowContents{%
        main path &%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\begin{enumerate}%
            \EnvironmentContents%
        \end{enumerate}\end{minipage}%
    }%
    \aftergroup\TableRowContents%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{usecase}{important use case}
    \actor{actor 1}
    \begin{mainpath}%
        \item step 1
        \item step 2
    \end{mainpath}
\end{usecase}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew that a command would work but, syntactically, an environment would be much better here, I think. Any ideas about the top alignment of "main path"?